# codeigniter mail - i can send email but i can't received it

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

I am using this code to send email via localhost.

```
function send_email(){
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');

        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('email');

        $config['protocol'] = "mail";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://mail.smsgt.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "myemail@smsgt.com"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "";
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "text";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";

        $ci->email->initialize($config);

        $ci->email->from('sender@email.com', 'company email');
        $ci->email->to('receiver@gmail.com'); 
        $ci->email->subject('test subject');
        $ci->email->message("testing email");

        $check = $ci->email->send();

        //echo $ci->email->print_debugger(); 

        if ($check){
          echo "true";
        }else{
          echo "false";    
        }
}
```

It always shows true but still I cant received it. What is problem with my codes? or is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Your smtp and port is not working**
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://mail.smsgt.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "25";

**Change into this**
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.mail.yahoo.com;ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
```

Comment: still i cant receive the email.. but thanks for the answer. :D

Comment: If nothing is working, you might also use another mail server which might luckily fix the issue. Here is the code I used to force CodeIgniter using sendmail instead:

$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$this->email->initialize($config);

Comment: that gives me error 'Unable to open a socket to Sendmail. Please check settings.'

Comment: change the protocol u are using, use this $config['protocol'] = 'smtp'; i knew it better erase also the mailpath :) cheers